# Replacing multiple parts of a string

Tags: php, str-replace

Let's say I have the following for example's sake:

```
$string = "^4Hello World ^5Foo^8Bar";
```

I'm currently using the following function to replace the carets and adjoining numbers, which is the closest I could get to what I wanted.

```
function addColours($input) {
    $var = $input;
    $var = str_replace('^0', '</span><span style="color: #000000">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^1', '</span><span style="color: #ff0000">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^2', '</span><span style="color: #00ff00">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^3', '</span><span style="color: #ffff00">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^4', '</span><span style="color: #0000ff">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^5', '</span><span style="color: #00ffff">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^6', '</span><span style="color: #ff00ff">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^7', '</span><span style="color: #ffffff">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^8', '</span><span style="color: #CC9933">', $var);
    $var = str_replace('^9', '</span><span style="color: #8D8D8D">', $var);
    return $var;
}
```

Which would return the following for the string.

```
</span><span style="color: #0000ff">Hello World </span><span style="color: #00ffff">Foo</span><span style="color: #CC9933">Bar
```

It works fine for the middle parts of the string, but obviously it's adding an unneeded `</span>` at the beginning of the string and it isn't closing the end tag.

Is there any way of making this work?

Thanks, Ben.

Comment: why not instead of `return $var;` simply do `return $var.'</span>';` ?

Comment: also, what about the first closing `</span>` (which actually doesn't seem to "close" anything) ?

Comment: I think the best solution is to split the string by `\^\d+` and wrap each part between span tags...

Comment: @alfasin I suppose your first suggestion would work regarding the end span. Still having trouble with the first span doing nothing.

Comment: Prepending `<span>` and appending `</span>` when all is said and done might not be pretty, but it is an obvious practical solution.

Comment: @Jon I have no control over the input, which is why I'm using this function.

Comment: @BenFortune: You have control over the output though.

Comment: @onetrickpony Is there a way to split them like that but keep the string that splits it, so I know what to wrap it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i was talking about in the comments:

```
$colorMap = array(
  '000000', // 0
  'ff0000', // 1
  '00ff00', // 2...     
);

$template = '<span style="color:#%s">%s</span>';

// split by "^" followed by 0-9
$parts = preg_split('/\^(\d)/', $string, -1,
            PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY + PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$result = '';

// rebuild string (odd elements are delimiters)
foreach($parts as $idx => $part)
  if((($idx % 2) === 0) && isset($colorMap[(int)$part]))
    $result .= sprintf($template, $colorMap[(int)$part], $parts[$idx + 1]);
```

Comment: PS- you can leave out the `isset()` check if your array contains all 10 elements.

Comment: That last update of the regex broke it btw, it worked as `'/(\^\d)/`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this then?

```
function addColours($input) {
    $out = '';
    $replacements = array(
            '1' => '000000',
            '2' => 'ff0000'
    );

    foreach(explode('^', $input) as $span) {
        if(in_array($span[0], array_keys($replacements))) {
            $out .= '<span style="color: #' .  $replacements[$span[0]] . '">' . substr($span, 1) . '</span>';
        } else {
            $out .= $span;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

$body = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ^1Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ^2It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

print addColours($body);
```

Comment: Works brilliantly, except when there's a caret at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Can you supply an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be running a preg replace, not a strreplace. The problem you will still run into here is that you need to find a patter such as '^4Some Sentance ^' so that you can end the span correctly. But what would happen if the entry was the last time a tag was used and it wasn't closed? It would fail.

I recommend switching to this format:

```
[4]Some sentence[/4]
```

Then you can run a simple str_replace correctly:

```
function addColours($input) {
    $replacements = array(
            '1' => '000000',
            '2' => 'ff0000'
    );

    foreach($replacements as $key => $value) {
        $input = str_replace("[$key]", '<span style="color: #' . $value . '">');
        $input = str_replace("[/$key]", '</span>');
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `^x` have to stay, unless there's a way to change them to wrap around the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents. It's the closest to the OPs code, and doesn't require manual rebuilding of the string.

```
function addColours($input) {

  $var = $input;

  $var = preg_replace('/\^0(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #000000">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^1(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #ff0000">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^2(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #00ff00">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^3(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #ffff00">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^4(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #0000ff">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^5(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #00ffff">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^6(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #ff00ff">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^7(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #ffffff">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^8(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #CC9933">$1</span>$2', $var);
  $var = preg_replace('/\^9(.*?)((\^\d)|($))/', '<span style="color: #8D8D8D">$1</span>$2', $var);

  return $var;

}
```