# php string replacement to html tag

Tags: php

I have the following string: ^1Flo^2wer^3Po^4wer
 You can see an example of what this does http://www.holysh1t.net/quake-live-colors-nickname/

I would like to be able to get this string and display it in color in my html page using PHP.

Unfortunately I have not been successful and wondered if anyone could help come up with some code to do this.

Thank you
Crouz

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: @MarcBWho said you were here to do other people's job? I guess you assume because I didn't post any code that I didn't try anything. I've been at it since last night, I have tried many things. If I had posted all of them, you probably would have complained that I had posted too many examples.

Comment: I had a problem with this too. There's another working example in my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833968/replacing-multiple-parts-of-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `/\^([1-7])([^\^]+)/` with `<span class="quake_colour_$1">$2</span>` and then change the colours in CSS as you prefer.

Paste into your CSS file:

```
.quake-colour-1 {
    color: red;
}
.quake-colour-2 {
    color: lime;
}
.quake-colour-3 {
    color: yellow;
}
.quake-colour-4 {
    color: blue;
}
.quake-colour-5 {
    color: cyan;
}
.quake-colour-6 {
    color: magenta;
}
.quake-colour-7 {
    color: white;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

And the code:

```
<?php
    $string = '^1Flo^2wer^3Po^4wer';

    $html = preg_replace('/\^([1-7])([^\^]+)/', '<span class="quake_colour_$1">$2</span>', $string);

    echo $html;
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/57157)

Which outputs:

```
<span class="quake_colour_1">Flo</span><span class="quake_colour_2">wer</span><span class="quake_colour_3">Po</span><span class="quake_colour_4">wer</span>
```

Alternately, you can do it using inline-css:

```
<?php
    class QuakeColour {
        private static $colours = array(
            1 => 'red',
            2 => 'lime',
            3 => 'yellow',
            4 => 'blue',
            5 => 'cyan',
            6 => 'magenta',
            7 => 'white'
        );

        private static function Replace($matches) {
            return '<span style="color: ' . self::$colours[$matches[1]] . '">' . $matches[2] . '</span>';
        }

        public static function Parse($string) {
            return preg_replace_callback('/\^([1-7])([^\^]+)/', 'QuakeColour::Replace', $string);
        }
    }

    $string = '^1Flo^2wer^3Po^4wer';
    var_dump(QuakeColour::Parse($string));
?>
```

Which outputs

```
string(144) "<span style="color: red">Flo</span><span style="color: lime">wer</span><span style="color: yellow">Po</span><span style="color: blue">wer</span>"
```

**Regex autopsy:**

- `\^` a literal `^` character. Needs to be escaped as `^` is a regex character.
- `([1-7])` a capturing group matching the digits from 1 to 7
- `([^\^]+)` a capturing group matching characters that are **not** `^` characters, repeated 1 or more times

Comment: @h20000000Thanks very much. I have been trying to come up with something since last night, to no avail. You're a saviour.

Comment: @Crouzilles Regex is awesome at *a lot* of things. This is one of them. :)

Comment: I think I need to learn regex, I've not come across it yet, it seems very powerful indeed.

Comment: @Crouzilles I've added a quick autopsy to the bottom of my answer so you can see what the regex means.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I am currently at a website called http://www.regular-expressions.info/, it is full of examples. What does the / (forward slash) mean in your regular expression? At the beginning and the end?

Comment: You have to start a regex with a character and end it with the same one. It can be anything. `|[0-9]|` will match a number from `0` to `9`, and so will `~[0-9]~`. The reason we use these is because we can add modifiers to the end of it. Eg. `/^[a-z]/` will match the first `a-z` character in a total string, but `/^[a-z]/m` will match the first `a-z` character in every line (because `/m` is "multi-line"). `/[a-z]/i` will both match `a-z` and `A-Z` as `/i` is "in case sensitive", etc. You can read all these modifiers for PHP here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

eveen though you should at least tried something before asking the question.. here's a basic algorith on how you could do it.

```
explode('^', $my_string)
foreach element in the exploded array:
    extract the first character and asociate it with a color
    print "<span style='background-color:" . $color . "'>" . $text . "</span>"
```

this migth give you the general idea how to do it. Hope this helps

Comment: @pleasedontbelongI did try many things, none of them worked. Thanks for your help, but please don't assume I didn't do any work beforehand.

Comment: lol sorry for the assumption :) but since you didn't posted any code before

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the ^X signs
Retrieve X of each part
Print  content_of_part_till_next_^ and

and you should be done

Quite easy to make a dummy thing of it, but you'll learn it by doing:

First try to split on ^ and work from that with string manipulation.
Try explode() or regex